# Spring: what is the programmatic equivalent of @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring

Consider the following setup:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:common.properties")
public class CommonConfig {

}
```

Now let's assume that I want some non-trivial logic behind how and what property sources I load in this config, and I want to use the properties API for this:

```
@Configuration
public class CommonConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    public void loadCommonConfig() {
        // Determine what properties to load and how...
        env.getPropertySources().addLast(...);
    }

}
```

I don't understand how I'm supposed to notify Spring that I am interested in `loadCommonConfig` to be called in the point in the life cycle where `@PropertySource` would have been handled. Simply returned the properties as a `@Bean` did not seem to work.

Comment: You well need to create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` for that purpose.

Comment: That worked. However I'm also interested in Gauthier JACQUES about how to do it in Spring boot by configuring the  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: Don't do it like that as that will destroy the default Spring Boot behavior.

Comment: There is no way to just tweak it to add my property sources during init smoehow without destroying the default spring boot behaviour...?

Comment: That is why there is an `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Comment: Well I went with your solution. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must declare a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` static bean for `@PropertySource` annotations to work (or use SpringBoot that will declare it for you).

You can manually load properties files when declaring this bean, with method `setLocations(...)`.

Here's an example :

```
@Configuration
public class CommonConfig {
...
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            ppc.setLocations(new FileSystemResource("/etc/webapp_properties/security-token.properties"),
                    new ClassPathResource("config/WebApp.properties"),
                    new ClassPathResource("config/" + System.getenv("CURRENTENV") + "/WebApp.properties"));
            return ppc;
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Yes but I'm using Spring boot which declares this bean and I don't want to change the way that Spring boot builds it.

Comment: The goal of Spring Boot is to ease configuration with auto-configuration, and to give you opportunity to customize configuration when needed. This is exactly your case : you just want to customize the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: So how do I configure the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer before the context refresh ? I can't seem to find an explanation for that in the Spring boot docs...

Comment: Just declare the bean PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in a @Configuration class, as mentioned in the snippet I gave. Spring Boot will detect you are declaring your own PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and will use it.

Comment: I edited the snippet to add the class definition around, maybe it is clearer like that.

Comment: I still don't understand - won't that circumvent how Spring boot configures the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` ?

Comment: I'll give this a vote if why `static` used is explained.

Comment: @fwonce Probably a bit late in the game but here's the reason for using static -  is to instantiate `propertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean very early in the spring container life-cycle, and for it to interfere with the processing of `@Value` annotations to replace them with the actual property values.

Comment: Check this from the official docs about using `static` - `Special consideration must be taken for @Bean methods that return Spring BeanFactoryPostProcessor (BFPP) types. Because BFPP objects must be instantiated very early in the container lifecycle, they can interfere with processing of annotations such as @Autowired, @Value, and @PostConstruct within @Configuration classes. To avoid these lifecycle issues, mark BFPP-returning @Bean methods as static.`
[link to spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)