# Reading multiple properties files with @PropertySource (SpringBoot)using wildcard character

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to read multiples properties files from a specific location, say *C:\config*.  I'm taking help of **@PropertySource** annotation. Is there a way to read these files in Springboot using some wildcard character e.g (*.properties). So what I intended to achieve is something like this

```
@PropertySource("*.properties") })
public class SomeClass{
}
```

If not, Is there a way to create these @PropertySource("foo.properties") or @PropertySource("bar.properties") programmatically and provide them to **@PropertySources** so that I can achieve this.

```
@PropertySources({
   @PropertySource("foo.properties"),
   @PropertySource("bar.properties")
})
```

The reason I want to achieve it so in future if I have to inject another property say future.properties, I do not have to modify the Java files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: what is the programmatic equivalent of @PropertySource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197175/spring-what-is-the-programmatic-equivalent-of-propertysource).

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

By command line arguments:
By this way you can tell Spring Boot to load our configuration files is by using command arguments. Spring Boot provides the argument  **spring.config.name** to set configuration files names seperated with a comma. The second command line argument is  **spring.config.location** in which you must set the locations where Spring Boot will find your externalised configuration files.

See example below:

```
java -jar yourApp.jar --spring.config.name=application,conf 
--spring.config.location=classpath:/external/properties/,classpath:/com/yourapp/configuration/
```

Answer (score 1):

**[PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)**

Annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding a PropertySource to Spring's Environment. To be used in conjunction with @Configuration classes.

Both traditional and XML-based properties file formats are supported — for example, "classpath:/com/myco/app.properties" or "file:/path/to/file.xml".

Resource location wildcards (e.g. **/*.properties) are not permitted; each location must evaluate to exactly one .properties resource.

${...} placeholders will be resolved against any/all property sources already registered with the Environment.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:test.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:test1.properties")
})
public class TestConfig {
    //...
}
```

You can using to wildcard character. but you need to consider PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer Deprecated.

**[PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)**

Deprecated.
as of 5.2; use org.springframework.context.support.**PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** instead which is more flexible through taking advantage of the Environment and PropertySource mechanisms.

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfig {

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer()
            throws IOException {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertyConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:/test/*.properties"));

        return propertyConfigurer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I found without overriding PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.
The trick is to implement a PropertySourceFactory with a fake properties file that serves the purpose only to load the factory. You have to put a fake properties file anyway.

```
@PropertySource(value = "placeholder.properties", factory = MyPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

At this point you can do anything, but you have no access to Spring context. So you need to use vanilla Java, like using ClassLoader.getResources (but with no
wildcard support) or you can use some classpath scanner, like corn-cps.